# MySQL JOIN ON with WHERE

Tags: sql, mysql, t-sql

I have 2 tables and want to query all the album data joined with the artist

`artists: artist_id | name`

`albums: album_id | artist_id | songs`

This gives me only the first row

```
SELECT * FROM albums JOIN artists ON artists.artist_id = albums.artist_id
```

I want to specify an album id

```
SELECT * FROM albums 
   WHERE album_id = 101 
JOIN artists ON artists.artist_id = albums.artist_id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WHERE` goes after the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    albums
JOIN    artists
ON      artists.artist_id = albums.artist_id
WHERE   album_id = 101
```